# Java MergeSort speedup using Multi Threading

Tags: java, multithreading, mergesort

I'm trying to implement a version of Mergesort using Multi Threading. First off, I know there's a billion threads (give or take...) on here, and I've read a few to no avail! I'm trying to show that using threads in parallel speeds the process up. The issue I'm having however is that my code does not display and speed up whatsoever, in fact, rather the opposite.

With one thread, my times is in the 10's of thousands. With two, my time increases to a few hundred thousand, then with 4 threads my time borders on 7 figures. My initial thoughts were to play around with the join() method and ensure that was in the right place, and have done so, but to no success.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and an example command line argument is something like;

java working 16 4 (For 4 threads).

Apologies for the lack of comments too throughout!

```
import java.util.*;

class working
{
  private static int sizeVector;
  private static int noThreads;
  static void sort(int[] input)
  {
    mergeSort(input, 0, input.length - 1, noThreads);
  }

  static void mergeSort(int[] array, int low, int high, int noThreadsUp)
  {
    //private int noThreadsUp;
    if (low < high)
    {
      int mid = (low+high)/2;
      if (noThreadsUp > 1)
      {
        NewThread td = new NewThread(array, low, mid, noThreadsUp/2);
        td.start();
        /*try{
        td.join();
        }catch(Exception e){}*/
        mergeSort(array, mid+1, high, noThreadsUp/2);
                try{
        td.join();//UNSURE WHERE THIS SHOULD BE
        }catch(Exception e){}
        merge(array, low, mid, high);

      }
      else
      {
      mergeSort(array, low, mid, noThreadsUp/2); 
      mergeSort(array, mid+1, high, noThreadsUp/2);
      merge(array, low, mid, high);
      }
    }
  }

  static void merge(int[] array, int low, int mid, int high)
  {
    int[] temp = new int[high - low + 1];
    int left = low;
    int right = mid+1;
    int k = 0;
    while (left <= mid && right <= high)
    {
      if(array[left] < array[right])
      {
        temp[k] = array[left];
        left = left+1;
      }
      else
      {
        temp[k] = array[right];
        right = right + 1;
      }
      k = k + 1;
    }
    if (left <= mid)
    {
      while(left <= mid)
      {
        temp[k] = array[left];
        left = left + 1;
        k = k + 1;
      }
    }
    else if (right <= high)
    {
      while(right <= high)
      {
        temp[k] = array[right];
        right = right + 1;
        k = k + 1;
      }
    }
    for (int m = 0; m < temp.length; m++)
    {
      array[low+m] = temp[m];

  }
}
  static int[] readInputArray()
  {

    int[] a = new int[sizeVector];
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeVector; i++)
    {
      Random generator = new Random();
      a[i] = generator.nextInt();
    }
    return a;
  }

  static void printArray(int[] array)
  {
    for(int i = 0; i<array.length; i++)
      System.out.println(array[i]);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    sizeVector = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    noThreads = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    int[] inputArray = readInputArray();
    System.out.println("INPUT ARRAY: ");
    printArray(inputArray);
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    sort(inputArray);
    long endTime = System.nanoTime();
    long finalTime = endTime - startTime;

    System.out.println("SORTED ARRAY: ");
    printArray(inputArray);      
    System.out.println("Time: " + finalTime);
  }

static class NewThread extends Thread 
  {
    private int low;
    private int mid;
    private int[] array;
    private int noThreadsDown;
    //private int threads;
    public NewThread(int[] array, int low, int mid, int noThreadsDown) 
    {
      this.low = low;//Ensure using the right start
      this.mid = mid;//Ensure using the right end
      this.array = array;
      this.noThreadsDown = noThreadsDown;
      //this.threads = threads;
    }
    public void run() 
    {

      mergeSort(array, low, mid, noThreadsDown/2);
      System.out.println(noThreadsDown);
    }
  }//End NewThread
}
```

Comment: Are you on java 7? Fork/Join might work well http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html

Comment: how many CPU cores has your computer  and what OS do you use?

Answer (score 2):

It could be best using RecurssionAcition class in java 7, which split up into two parts left and right.

```
Sum left  = new Sum(array, low, mid);
Sum right = new Sum(array, mid, high);
left.fork();
long rightAns = right.compute();
long leftAns   = left.join();
return leftAns + rightAns;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here some code that works.

```
public class TestMergeSort{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        // Threaded merge sort (and printing)
        int[] toSort = {191,2,3,5,6,7,5,3,21,3,4};
        printArr(toSort);  
        concurrentMergeSort(toSort); 
        printArr(toSort);  
    }

    public static void concurrentMergeSort(int[] toSort){
        int[] tmpArray = new int[toSort.length];

        try{
            // Start the mergesort
            ConcurrentMergeSort sort = new ConcurrentMergeSort(toSort, tmpArray, 0, toSort.length - 1);
            sort.start();
            sort.join();

        } catch(InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static void printArr(int[] a){
        for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
            System.out.print(a[i] + " ,");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}



public class ConcurrentMerge extends Thread{
    private int[] a;
    private int[] tmpArray;
    private int leftPos;
    private int rightPos;
    private int rightEnd;

    public ConcurrentMerge(int[] a, int[] tmpArray, int leftPos, int rightPos, int rightEnd){
        this.a = a;
        this.tmpArray = tmpArray;
        this.leftPos = leftPos;
        this.rightPos = rightPos;
        this.rightEnd = rightEnd; 
    }

    public void run(){
        int leftEnd = rightPos - 1;
        int tmpPos  = leftPos;
        int numElements = rightEnd - leftPos + 1;

        // Main loop
        while( leftPos <= leftEnd && rightPos <= rightEnd )
            if( a[ leftPos ] <= a[ rightPos ] )
                tmpArray[ tmpPos++ ] = a[ leftPos++ ];
            else
                tmpArray[ tmpPos++ ] = a[ rightPos++ ];

        // Copy rest of the left half
        while( leftPos <= leftEnd )  
            tmpArray[ tmpPos++ ] = a[ leftPos++ ];

        // Copy rest of the right half
        while( rightPos <= rightEnd ) 
            tmpArray[ tmpPos++ ] = a[ rightPos++ ];

        // Copy tmpArray back
        for( int i = 0; i < numElements; i++){
            a[ rightEnd ] = tmpArray[ rightEnd-- ];
        }
    }

}


import java.util.Arrays;

public class ConcurrentMergeSort extends Thread{

    private int[] a;
    private int[] tmpArray;
    private int left;
    private int right;

    public ConcurrentMergeSort(int[] a, int[] tmpArray, int left, int right){
        this.a = a;
        this.tmpArray = tmpArray;
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right; 
    }

    public void run(){
        if(this.left < this.right){
            try{
                int center = ( this.left + this.right ) / 2;
                ConcurrentMergeSort p = new ConcurrentMergeSort(this.a, this.tmpArray, this.left, center);
                ConcurrentMergeSort q = new ConcurrentMergeSort(this.a, this.tmpArray, center + 1, this.right);
                ConcurrentMerge r = new ConcurrentMerge(this.a, this.tmpArray, this.left, center + 1, this.right);

                // Sort
                p.start();
                q.start();
                p.join();
                q.join();

                // Merge
                r.start();
                r.join();
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public int[] getA(){
        return this.a;
    }

}
```

Comment: SO is more for answers, rather than code sharing.  Code snippets are suitable, but large blocks of code don't make for good answers.  Can you rephrase your answer into an explanation of what works, along with the important snippets?  An explanation of why the OP saw the apparent slowdown would also be good.